# Postfix not forwarding to .forward address

Tags: postfix, gmail, forwarding

I have a VPS with Postfix. E-mail is working - I can send messages to and from it, tested using `mutt` and my GMail account.

However, I want to forward all mails send to my VPS to my GMail account so it's all in one place.

I tried specifying my gmail address in my `.forward`, but after doing so, e-mails just get lost completely. They don't show up in `mutt`, and they don't show up in GMail.

`mail.log` suggest that the e-mail was sent on, and there are no errors that I can see in `mail.err`. From my perspective it looks as if GMail is just receiving the e-mail and discarding it, but that can't be right!

**Addendum:** Specifying my forwarding e-mail address in `/etc/postfix/virtual` leads to the same result:

```
Apr  4 08:49:28 vps-375 postfix/smtpd[16235]: 8062044D1B2F: client=mail-qw0-f48.google.com[209.85.216.48]
Apr  4 08:49:28 vps-375 postfix/cleanup[16239]: 8062044D1B2F: message-id=<BANLkTina6U==71+ZW-bafMbE6QCHqeYQ4g@mail.gmail.com>
Apr  4 08:49:28 vps-375 postfix/qmgr[15970]: 8062044D1B2F: from=<redacted@gmail.com>, size=1581, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr  4 08:49:29 vps-375 postfix/smtp[16240]: 8062044D1B2F: to=<redacted+domain@gmail.com>, orig_to=<dave@domain.net>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[209.85.143.27]:25, delay=1.3, delays=0.41/0.02/0.36/0.52, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1301903372 m53si9513199wej.191)
Apr  4 08:49:29 vps-375 postfix/qmgr[15970]: 8062044D1B2F: removed
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out the problem here was GMail not showing e-mails forwarded back to it. Sending an e-mail from other addresses were correctly forwarded. GMail seems to discard the messages that are forwarded back to it.

Comment: This was my problem to! You can send your self an email from here using a   [service](http://send-email.org/)

Answer (score 5):

For simplicity append `/etc/aliases' with an entry like this will which will duplicate all mail to a user:

`jonathan: jonathanross@gmail.com`

This is slightly different and will also copy it to the local user's Maildir/box:

`jonathan: jonathan, jonathanross@gmail.com`

You get the idea. Follow that with `newaliases` to build a .db version of that file.

AFAIK this is needed in `main.cf` for that method:

`alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases`

`alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases`

If that doesn't work for whatever platform reason then a `virtual_alias_domains = me.com` entry in `main.cf`, another line in `main.cf` as `virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual` and a flat file in this format in `/etc/postfix` will do it:

`me@me.com jonathanross@gmail.com`

followed by `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual` should do it.

Comment: This led to the same outcome as in my question - `mail.log` showed an e-mail being sent, but it was never recieved in my GMail account.